# Routing to specific XEP-0114 instances backing a single domain in ejabberd?

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I've got a simple ejabberd 18.09 setup running a test component under the domain: `test.localhost`.

The configuration is super simple:

```
port: 8888
module: ejabberd_service
hosts:
   "test.localhost":
       password: "secret"
```

I've got my XEP-0114 / XMPP component setup to run multiple instances via a Procfile:

```
test1: ./testcomponent --address localhost:8888 --secret ... --name test.localhost
test2: ./testcomponent --address localhost:8888 --secret ... --name test.localhost
test3: ./testcomponent --address localhost:8888 --secret ... --name test.localhost
```

Now when i send a message to any contact under `test.localhost`, one of these is guaranteed to get it. That's great! That seems like for any given xmpp component, you can scale out to multiple hosts and nodes without worrying about a single point of failure.

Is there a way to always route messages sent to `user1@test.localhost` to `test1` process above? Maybe with a specific presence message sent by the test1 instance with `user1@test.localhost` as the contact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the option “domain_balancing” with value `bare_source`. It will ensure all packets from a given user gets to the same component.
Documentation is here: https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/guide/advanced/

Comment: Great, thanks! It sounds like the routing is still ultimately up to ejabberd and domain_balancing is more of a suggestion or seed on which available component to route to?

Which is good enough for me for now!